# Retweet latest tweet using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Ive been playing around with the `tweepy` python module to create a twitter bot that retweets every tweet from a few specific accounts I follow. I have been able to follow the module documentation and have successfully retweeted the tweets of all the accounts. As most of you might know a few accounts do not tweet as regularly as others and I dont want to retweet the same tweet multiple time. I couldnt get a definitive solution about `'getting the most recent tweet'` from the docs so i came up with a solution of storing the `tweet id` with the account id as a `key value pair in a dictionary`. Before retweeting I check the id to see if they match. If yes, I skip the tweet

Is this a good solution or have I overlooked a simpler method and should go through the docs again?

Answer (score 0):

I have a running code that does exactly this, but is not that simple. In my case, people may retweet from others, and additionally, change the tweet a little bit. So I need to "see" if it is or not the same subject.

I achieve this by parsing the tweet, removing generic words (a, the, un, ...), getting the main words, and then, as you said, storing them on a variable. In my case I choose using pickle and a FIFO system. So, when a tweets came by, I check the most relevant words against a list of relevant words, accepting 1 word as deviation, and only them, decide to retweet it or not. In fact, I tweet it again, instead of retweeting. If you only retweet, perhaps you can store the tweet id only and you will be good. But as I said, be carefull that your following accounts may tweet the same thing, and the will have different IDs.

--- FIFO ---

```
class Fifo:

    def __init__(self, max_limit):
        self.data = [[], []]
        self.max_limit = max_limit

    def append(self, value):
        self.data[1].append(value)
        if self.max_limit > 0:
            if len(self.data[0]) + len(self.data[1]) > self.max_limit:
                return self.pop()

    def pop(self):
        if not self.data[0]:
            self.data.reverse()
            self.data[0].reverse()
        return self.data[0].pop()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data[0]) + len(self.data[1])

    def tolist(self):
        temp = (self.data[0])[:]
        temp.reverse()
        return temp + self.data[1]
```

Comment: Yes I realized this yesterday. Im using pickle to store my dictionary. Once I have have the valid checks in to skip retweeting the same thing twice, ill look into the problem youve pointed put

Comment: I added on my response the FIFO code I used which helped me out.